# Why only Bakoma TeX?

Tags: bakoma

I have used Bakoma TeX and LyX, and many other LaTeX editors.

I really liked Bakoma's WYSIWYG, but it is so expensive.

Why is there so few WYSIWYG among the numerous LaTeX editors.

Is the technology of Bakoma TeX unknown? is it tricky? or is it patented?

I am hoping to see the price to be competitive (or to see some other alternative editors with better icons).

Comment: I think this would garner primarily option-based answers.

Comment: What is your question? There is a list of [LaTeX editors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides). Is it only about the WYSIWYG system? LyX has it too, and perhaps some others as well.

Comment: There is of course LyX, which seems similar?

Comment: Never used any of them, but is Scientific Word similar to Bakoma?

Comment: I tried briefly all of them. They are very nice tools to start learning because you can generate a lot of code (interacting with the program) that later you can examine... and after a couple of days they remind you why WYSIWYG is a bad idea if you want to have control over your document.

Comment: Another interesting but abandoned project was Sciwriter http://sciwriter.soft112.com/